# find out what instructions write to this memory address olly dbg cheat engine

Tags: debugging, assembly, ollydbg, cheat-engine

Is there an option in ollydbg to find out what pieces of code write to a memory address ? Just like Cheat Engine shows all the assembly instructions that write to a specific address.
"breakpoint --> memory" does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,
With olly open and debugging a certain program, go to View tab>Memory or `Alt+M`
then, find the memory address (first you have to choose the memory part of the program like .data or .bss) and then click on the address (or addresses selecting multiple with `Shift`) with the right mouse button and hover to Breakpoint then you'll be able to choose the to break the program when it writes or reads the address

A good thing to do is first find the address on cheatEngine then use the breakpoint on ollydbg.